# Resume flexslider after touch/swipe

Tags: jquery, flexslider

Is there any way to resume the auto-playing of a Flexslider slideshow after a touch event? Right now it appears that once I swipe to navigate, the slideshow stops..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE FOR FLEXISLIDER 2**

The `resume()` event are no longer exist, the correct solution is using the **after** callback and use the event `after` in the initialization

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider(
    ...
    after: function(slider){ 
        slider.pause(); 
        slider.play(); 
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here:
https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/21

The question has been asked before, and the answer is that it is possible to do what you're asking, however, it is a specific part of the design of the slider that it stops on a touch event, simply for better usability.